# Adding onload to body for certain pages

Tags: php, functions

I am looking for a function to add

```
<body onload="prepareFrame('https://airtable embed URL here')">
```

to certain wordpress pages only.

I know how to add a custom body class but not an onload statement.

```
add_filter('body_class', 'custom_body_class');
function custom_body_class($classes) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->ID == 346) {
        $classes[] = 'services';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `body_class` filter to add additional attributes. I'm not sure if this is the best option out there. Maybe javascript would be better for this.

```
function my_add_body_attribute($classes) {
    echo 'onload="doyourthing" ';
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('body_class', 'my_add_body_attribute');
```